# How to force ag grid to stop using vertical scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ag-grid

I'm trying to disable the vertical scrollbar inside the ag-grid. I've tried using overflow-y: hidden, inside of my CSS however it hasn't worked.

I've also been following this https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/801 but haven't had any success.

Comment: Have you tried `domLayout: 'autoHeight',` in gridOptions or is this not the result you are after?

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well, but I'm getting an error that says "Property 'setDomLayout' does not exist on type 'GridApi'. This is the code I'm using: function setAutoHeight() {
  gridOptions.api.setDomLayout('autoHeight');
  // auto height will get the grid to fill the height of the contents,
  // so the grid div should have no height set, the height is dynamic.
  document.querySelector('#myGrid').style.height = '';
}